# What does <<- symbol mean in rails?

Tags: ruby

**I have this method in rails model class**

```
def self.custom_order
  order(<<-AJ)
    (
case id
WHEN 1
THEN 1
WHEN 4
THEN 2
WHEN 5
THEN 3
ELSE 4
END
) ASC
  AJ
end
```

what does <<- symbol do in this method?.

Comment: You used many tags, but forgot the main one; Ruby. See the Ruby literals [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html).

Comment: Also duplicates various others: http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%3C%3C-

Answer (score 1):

It will create a `doc` for your multiple lines code.

Answer (score 0):

it was called [heredoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents). The `heredoc` starts on the line following `<< HEREDOC` and ends with the next line that starts with `HEREDOC`.

You may indent the ending identifier if you place a `-` after `<<`

In your case, the `heredoc` starts with `<<- AJ` and ends with `AJ`.